# Dynamic values in Lookup View Filter Criteria

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I have two entities (`entity1` and `entity2`)that have `event` field. `entity1` has the `subgrid` with the records from `entity2`.

Is it possible to set lookup view filter criteria to show only record from `entity2` that have the same value in the `event` field as `entity1`?

Comment: 2016 on premise

Comment: is the `event` field a lookup ?

Comment: Yes it is a lookup field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done via a Quick View

1. Create a Quick View in the `event` field entity
2. Put a SubGrid to `Entity2` in the Quick View, list all records from `Entity2`
3. Remove the subgrid you have in the `Entity1` form
4. Insert the Quick View you created before in the `Entity1` form, link it to the `event` field
5. That should be it to accomplish the requirement "display all the `Entity2` records related to the record referenced by the `event` field in `Entity1`",

Comment: When you write `entity` field, you mean `event` field?

Comment: Yeah, messed that up, fixed